# glossaries: How to customize list of symbols with additional column for units?

Tags: symbols, lists, glossaries, description, units

I want to add an additional column to the list of symbols for inserting the belonging units to the preceding variables.

In my case, it is necessary to use three different and independent `glossary`-lists (`acronymslist`, `symbolslist` and `glossary`) like shown below. However, the third column should be used only in the `symbolslist`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}                           % documentclass: scrbook
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist
\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
    \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
        description={Geometrical value},
        type=symbolslist}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST ========================================
    \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR MAIN GLOSSARY ========================================
    \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long]   % list of symbols
    \printglossary[type=main]                     % main glossary

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image]

---

As expected, this MWE creates three different types of lists what is entirely correct. Now, I want to add a third column only to the list of symbols for inserting the units. It would be great if we can create something beautiful like the following table-layout.

---

**Screenshot of the final (desired) state:**

[image]

---

I have borrowed this shapely layout from [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174665/78784). Unfortunately, the belonging MWE doesn't work together with `scrbook`-class. Is there any other possibility to expand my own code from the top to generate such a layout (including the `hrule`)?

---

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If i replace on of the 3 entries with my custom entry then it generates 4 entries and wont remove the old one, even though it isnt in the code anymore. Why is that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest to use a separate `unit` key for the symbol unit and refer to it with `\glsunit`. (Alternative: Use the `user1`...`user6` keys for this feature)

In addition, this key must be used in the glossarystyle. I've defined a new style based on the already provided `long3col` style which displays the symbols in the requested order.

```
\documentclass{book}                           
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
    \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
        description={Geometrical value},
        unit={},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
        description={Height of tower},
        unit={\si{m}},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{energyconsump}{name=\ensuremath{P},
        description={Energy consumption},
        unit={\si{kW}},
        type=symbolslist}




% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST ========================================
    \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR MAIN GLOSSARY ========================================
    \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols
    \printglossary[type=main]                     % main glossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but when I copy and paste your MWE, then compile it, I got nothing but a white page. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Have you run the `makeglossaries` script?

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: You need to compile with `pdflatex`, then `makeglossaries, then `pdflatex` again.

Comment: I only have `makeindex` if that what you mean. I would be grateful if you could show me how to apply your answer using `\makenoidxglossaries` since I already use it in my thesis, and I am afraid I will mess things up if I changed it.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: That's another question, sorry.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: You will get into trouble with `makeindex` here anyway due to the special content written to the glossary files. `\makenoidxglossaries` is no good solution, in my point of view. `makeglossaries` is the better variant and is a script that is contained in the `glossaries` distribution

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I haven't used `makeindex` ever, so I don't know if there is another package to load or command to define. I will try reading about it or asking a separate question. Thanks again for help.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: See the documentation and change `\makenoidxglossaries` into `\makeglossaries`

Comment: This code resulted in empty file for me

Comment: Why `\ensuremath{h}` instead of `$h$`?

Comment: Is it possible to use tabularray? I know it's based on a predefined style, but I tought renewenvironment should have fixed the things but it doesn't

Answer (score 9):

Just adding to Christian's answer: to use the unit macros inside the `\si{unit}` command defined by `siunitx` such as `\metre` and `\kilo\watt` used in his MWE, one should add the command `\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}` before setting any entries.

It is better explained in [This Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192336/add-custom-key-to-display-units-in-glossary-with-siunitx).