# How can I add a list of mathematical variables to my appendix?

Tags: lists, glossaries, appendices

I would like to include a section in my appendix which shows a list of mathematical symbols, operators, etc. with a textual explanation right next to them. Ideally they should be separated by dots (like in the table of contents).

How can I achieve that? Is that what glossary is for?

Here is my current setup:

```
...
\appendix{}
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Notation}
THIS IS WHERE THE LIST SHOULD APPEAR

\section{Appendix 2}
Lorem ipsum ...
...
```

EDIT: Some more code from my setup

```
\usepackage[section,numberedsection=autolabel,symbols]{glossaries}
...
\glsaddall{}
\printglossary[type=main,style=long,nonumberlist]
```

And here my glossary entries

```
\newglossaryentry{pressure}
{
  name={\ensuremath{p}},
  description={Pressure}
}
\newglossaryentry{acceleration}
{
  name={\ensuremath{g}},
  description={Acceleration}
}
```

Comment: Something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units/269571?s=5|0.0000#269571 perhaps? `glossaries` can do this almost out of the box

Comment: That might be a good start. Thx for pointing it out!

Comment: mmh.. the look is not really what I want. it gives me separate chapter headers and does go into my "notation" section. Is there any way I can make my own glossary. I just need a list of variables with their definitions ideally separated by dots

Comment: Perhaps you should start first providing a MWE

Comment: You could also just define a tabular environment in the section, what would be against it?

Comment: In my thesis, I thought about `glossaries` but in the end I just did it manually and used the `description` environment to format the list of symbols with their explanations. I didn't want dots though, not sure how easy it would be to get dots with `description`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I kind of handling it right now with `glossaries`. Are you aware of any good style option for a list of symbols?

Comment: @user2426316: `good`?  That's no well defined. I personally would **not** use `dots` as requested, so for me that's not good.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just would like to fill the paper. right now everything is sitting at the left. Some spacing between symbol and description would be ideal (and some `dots` to fill that spacing)

Comment: @user2426316: Add your code to your post and I've a look into it. Most likely it's necessary to change an existing style

Comment: @ChristianHupfer edited my question

Comment: @user2426316: Yes, but it leaves any further effort to other users or me -- not a single symbol is there, no `\newglossaryentry` etc. I won't try an answer until there's some more support.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there is not much to my `newglossaryentry`s. added them above

Comment: @user2426316: Is it possible to provide a working document? Is this that difficult? won't glue one fragment to the other one and making a compilable document out of it. I wonder if I post such fragments if you wouldn't be puzzled too.

Comment: For the simpler case of a list of variables, I think the [nomencl](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package notation is simpler, just a `\nomenclature{$a$}{Meaning of $a$}`. By default, you won't get the format you want, but section 5.5 of its documentation shows something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of automation, I went with a simple `tabular` (actually, a `longtabu` for multi-page compatibility). A `\quad` for indentation makes enough horizontal white space, manual `\\[3pt]` spacing to group the list by starting letter.

#### Preview

[image: list of symbols]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}} 
\textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} \\
$a\in A$ & \textbf{arc} (directed) from vertex $v_i$ to $v_j$, set of arcs \\
$\phantom{a\in{}}A^\text{p}_{v}$ & \quad arriving arcs into vertex $v$ (\emph{predecessor}) \\
$\phantom{a\in{}}A^\text{s}_{v}$ & \quad leaving arcs from vertex $v$ (\emph{successor}) \\[3pt]
$b \in B_{e}$ & \textbf{building}, set of buildings along edge $e$ \\
$b_\text{eff}$ & concurrence effect (parameter) \\[3pt]
$c\in C$ & \textbf{commodity}, set of commodities \\[3pt]
$e\in E$ & \textbf{edge}, set of edges \\[3pt]
& \dots \\[3pt]
$v\in V$ & \textbf{vertex}, set of vertices
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't break over pages if the list is considerably longer

Comment: Indeed. As I wrote, I actually use the `longtabu` environment. For the sake of a MWE, I omitted the dependency.