# How to make list of mathematics symbols in a book?

Tags: symbols, lists

I want to make a list of mathematical symbols in a book. I know that using the command `\index{}`, we can make a list of symbols.

Is there any such easy way to make list of mathematical symbols?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Packages `nomencl`, `glossaries` ....

Comment: For example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units

Comment: You mean like in [my book about geometry and topology](https://zenodo.org/record/50395) (starting at page 161)? See [LaTeX sources](https://github.com/MartinThoma/GeoTopo), esepcially `Symbolverzeichnis.tex`.