# Glossaries: error when compiling

Tags: glossaries, classicthesis

I have a problem with Latex  [pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)] and specially with glossaries. I've have tried to write a glossary, a list of acronyms and a list of symbols (referring, fot this latter, to this link: 
[glossaries: How to customize list of symbols with additional column for units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units) ) and everything seems to go right but I have the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{1}}}
```

I have tried to simplify my code based on the Miede's ClassicThesis. Hope is enough or not too much: I can't say what is helpful for you and I apologize for that, I'm a new user of Latex and this site.

Thesis2.tex:

```
% A Classic Thesis Style 
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} 
\documentclass[ twoside]{scrreprt} % Classe: Report

\input{Thesis-config2}

\begin{document}

%\dominitoc
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{English} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Contents2} 


\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

The \gls{latex} typesetting markup ...  other glossary \gls{other}

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{gcd} \\

This is height \gls{height} and this velocity \gls{velocity}
\end{document}
```

Thesis-config2.txt

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{parts,%drafting,%
                 listings,floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
                      subfig,eulerchapternumbers,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing}
                 {classicthesis}   
\usepackage{classicthesis}                                      



% 3. Load packages

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Encoding inputs
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel} % Select language (last most used)               
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics

\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)


\usepackage{siunitx} % International system units


% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions

\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment

\usepackage{caption} % Ita: didascalie
\captionsetup{font=small} % format=hang,
\usepackage{subfig}  


% 6. PDFLaTeX, hyperreferences and citation backreferences

% Using PDFLaTeX

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 


% Glossary, list of symbols and nomenclature

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,acronym,xindy]{glossaries} 
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit} % Inserts unit column


\makeglossaries
\input{glossary-defs}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
    \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
    \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
    \hline
    \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
    & \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}
```

Contents2.tex

```
% Table of Contents
%*******************************************************
\refstepcounter{dummy} % to refere to a chapter not numbered
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents} % bookmark to the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents % makes the table of contents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace \spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}

\cleardoublepage

% List of Figures
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename} 
% \pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures

%\cleardoublepage
%*******************************************************
% List of Tables
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
%   \pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables

%\cleardoublepage

%*******************************************************
% List of Listings
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
%\pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
\lstlistoflistings 

%\cleardoublepage

%*******************************************************
% Acronyms
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
%   \pdfbookmark[0]{Acronyms}{acronyms}
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
%\cleardoublepage

%*******************************************************
% List of symbols
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols
%\cleardoublepage

%*******************************************************
% Glossary 

\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}
%   \pdfbookmark[0]{Glossary}{glossary}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Glossary}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Glossary}}
    \printglossary[type=main]      % main glossary  
%   \cleardoublepage
```

glossary-defs.tex

```
\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific document}
}

\newglossaryentry{other}
{
name=other,
description={example of description }
}

\newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
description={Height of tower},
unit={\si{m}},
type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{velocity}{name=\ensuremath{V},
description={Velocity},
unit={\si{m/s}},
type=symbolslist}
```

So my questions are:

1. What is that error? Why the PDF seems to be right despite the error?
2. Why the glossary names are displayed in that way? (ex. lo@latex@name)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}                                      

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries} 

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific document}
}

\newglossaryentry{other}
{
name=other,
description={example of description }
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary

The \gls{latex} typesetting markup ...  other glossary \gls{other}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a trimmed down MWE, which reproduces the problem. (Different error message but same problem.) If you comment out classicthesis, the error goes away, so I'm guessing the conflict lies there.

Comment: Hi Nicola! Yes, I see that the source of the problem can be the ClassicThesis style. Isn't there a way to solve the problem? Should I use another package insted of Miede's style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tldr:** Most (but not all) of the `list` styles are incompatible with `classicthesis`, so the style needs to be switched.

---

The problem is caused by the way `\item` is redefined with `classicthesis`. The following is a trimmed down MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific document}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\glossentryname {latex}] sample
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

With `classicthesis`, this produces the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \letcs {\glo@name 
                             }{glo@\glsdetoklabel{latex}@name}\expandafter ...
l.23 \item[\glossentryname {latex}]
                                    sample
```

Without `classicthesis`, there's no error. It seems that `classicthesis` tries to expand the label's argument. Protecting the fragile command fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific document}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\protect\glossentryname {latex}] sample
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Since the `\item` is embedded within the glossary style, the simplest method is to use a different style. For example:

```
\printglossary[style=index]
```

The alternative is to define a style that protects all the commands within the optional argument of `\item`. For example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific document}
}

\newglossarystyle{plist}
{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\protect\glsentryitem{##1}%
     \protect\glstarget{##1}{\protect\glossentryname {##1}}]
     \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription \space ##2%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=plist]

\gls{latex}

\end{document}
```

I don't really recommend this method as you're unlikely to want to gather `\glsentrytarget` and `\glsentryitem` in a command for later use, as they
are specific to the glossary. (`\glsentrytarget` provides the hypertarget, which must be unique and `\glsentryitem` is dependent on a counter that is reset and incremented in the glossary.)

In answer to your second question `\glo@latex@name` is the internal command used to store the value of the `name` key for the entry with the label `latex`. You shouldn't ever need to use this explicitly. (This value can simply be obtained using `\glsentryname{latex}`.)

*Edit:* As from v4.26, `glossaries` now checks if `classicthesis` has been loaded. If it has, the default style is switched from `list` to `index`, which is the closest matching style.

Note that the `nolist` option mentioned in the other answer simply prevents the automatic loading of `glossary-list.sty`. It doesn't automatically switch the style. For example, with pre `glossaries` v4.26:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[nolist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific document}
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\gls{latex}

\end{document}
```

The error switches to:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary style `list' undefined.
```

There is actually a style in `glossary-list.sty` that works with `classicthesis` and that's the `listdotted` style, which becomes unavailable with `nolist`. The key point is to select a style that's compatible with `classicthesis`.

In the case, such as with `classicthesis`, where you are unable to use the `list` style, the `index` style is the closest match. Note that the tabular-like styles, such as `long`, don't allow page breaks within the description, so `index` works better for long descriptions. However, an adjustment is required for multi-paragraph descriptions.

For comparison, here's an example of the `list` style:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=list,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% sample entries provided by glossaries for testing:
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-multipar}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Here's the closest matching `index` style with adjustment (requires at least `glossaries` v4.26):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=index,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% adjust "index" style to allow multi-paragraph descriptions:
\renewcommand{\glstreeitem}{%
 \parindent0pt\par\hangindent40pt
 \everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}

% sample entries provided by glossaries for testing:
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-multipar}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

It's not an exact match, but it's fairly close.

The `altlist` style starts the description on the next line. Here's an example of `altlist`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=altlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% sample entries provided by glossaries for testing:
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-multipar}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

The closest non-list match is again the `index` style, but with another adjustment (again requires at least v4.26):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=index,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% adjust "index" style to allow multi-paragraph descriptions:
\renewcommand{\glstreeitem}{%
 \parindent0pt\par\hangindent40pt
 \everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}
\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{\par
  \glstreeitem\parindent\hangindent}

% sample entries provided by glossaries for testing:
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-multipar}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

The difference in the font used by the label stems from the use of `scrreprt` as the class which uses sans-serif for the `\item` label in the `description` environment. Since the `index` style doesn't use a list environment, it's unaffected.

There's a [complete list of all predefined styles with examples](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/) for comparison.

Comment: Nicola, I have changed the code as you said, that is

Comment: Nicola, I have changed the code as you said, that is \printglossary[style=index]. 
All the errors are gone! Thanke you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find where exactly classicthesis.sty redefines anything related to the error you're reporting. What I did find is a note in the 'manual' saying: If you want to use the glossaries package, take care of loading it with the following options: \usepackage[style=long,nolist]{glossaries}. 
Can't blame classicthesis for everything, can you?

Comment: Hi PhilipPirrip, you and Nicola have found the problem: it should always used an option for the style: in this way there are no errors. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

classicthesis loves to use in all sort of places `\spacedlowsmallcaps` (and similar commands) which uses `\MakeTextLowercase` and sometimes (depending on the packages options) also the `soul` to change the letter spacing. 
Both `\MakeTextLowercase` and the `soul` commands are a bit picky regarding their argument.

In this case you get the error as classicthesis redefines `\descriptionlabel` to add this \spacedlowsmallcaps. You can redefine `\descriptionlabel` to get rid of the error:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\textls[80]{\scshape{#1}}}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,
description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific document}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\glossentryname {latex}] sample
\end{description}

\end{document}
```