# Problem printing glossary

Tags: glossaries

I have a problem printing my glossary.
The entries can be resolved in text (\gls{API} -> Application Programming Interface). Also the editor gives hints, for what is possible (my list of glossary entries)

But \printglossaries does not print the used entries.

```
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} 
\loadglsentries{frontbackmatter/GlossaryEntries}
\makeglossaries
```

Loaded in config

```
\newglossaryentry{API}{%
    name={Application Programming Interface},%
    description={(API) random description text}}
```

The glossary entry

```
\include{chapters/basics/api}
```

Here the references are used in text

```
\cleardoublepage\include{frontbackmatter/Glossary}
```

Here I load the glossary chapter

```
%*******************************************************
% Glossary
%*******************************************************
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}    
{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace          
\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Glossary}{Glossary}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Glossary}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Glossary}}
\chapter*{Glossary}
%\gls{API}  %<-- Wont work either to use an entry in the same document
\printglossaries
```

Finally the chapter where I want to print the glossary.

Do you have any ideas why it is not printed but in text referenced?

Edit here my generated .gls file

```
\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}\glossarypreamble
\providecommand*\glsXpageXglsnumberformat[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\glsnumberformat{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextsf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textsf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtexttt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\texttt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextmd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textmd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextsl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textsl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXtextsc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\textsc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\emph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXglshypernumber[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\glshypernumber{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhyperrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hyperrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhypersf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hypersf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhypertt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hypertt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhyperbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hyperbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhypermd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hypermd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhyperit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hyperit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhyperup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hyperup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhypersl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hypersl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhypersc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hypersc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXhyperemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\hyperemph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXpageXglsignore[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{page}\glsignore{#2}}
\begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader
\glsgroupheading{A}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{API-Gateway}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{2}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{4}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{11}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{13}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{15}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{17}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{20}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{22}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{27}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{API-Portal}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{3}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{27}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{API}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{B}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{B2B}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{B2C}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{B2E}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{C}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Client}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{8}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{10}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{13}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{15}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{18}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{22}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{24}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{26}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{27}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Cloud}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{3}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Cluster}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{24}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{25}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{E}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{XML}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{8}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{G}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Getter_und_Setter}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{9}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{J}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{JSON}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{8}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{L}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{LDAP}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{14}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{LB}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{24}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{25}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{O}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{OAuth}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{11}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{P}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Pattern}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{13}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{R}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{REST}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{S}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Service}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{8}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{10}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{11}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{13}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{15}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{17}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{20}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{22}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{24}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{26}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{SOAP}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{2}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{8}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{9}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{11}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Software-as-a-service}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{vi}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}}}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{Swagger}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{18}\delimR 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{20}\delimN 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{24}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{U}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{URI}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{ix}, 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{6}}}%
\end{theglossary}\glossarypostamble
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It's difficult to diagnose with only code fragments. It would help if you could provide [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem. Since you have a `.gls`, it's clear that `xindy` was included in your document build (which is usually the first stumbling block). Did you rerun LaTeX after `xindy`? There's a diagnostic tool described in my answer to [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233) which might help.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to make a MWE, I recognized it was because of the classicthesis template I have to use for my bachelor thesis and because I used TexStudio I got no error messages.

So first I had to fix texstudios preferences to use xindy there: [Xindy invisible to TeXStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/xindy-invisible-to-texstudio)

Then I got error messages and I found the solution here: [Glossaries: error when compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333521/glossaries-error-when-compiling)

```
\printglossary[style=index]
```