# Classicthesis: error \glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{xxvii}}}

Tags: glossaries, classicthesis, roman-numerals

When I compile with TexStudio a document I obtain the following error:

```
    ! Missing { inserted.
    <to be read again> 
               ^
    l.68 \glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{xxvii}}}
                                     \glsgroupskip
    A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
    You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
    so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
    (If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)
```

This happened the first time when I tried to use "dottedtoc" in the classicthesis configuration, but from that moment if I leave "dottedtoc" or not the error appears. 
I know that I should load a MWE, but I don't know how to reproduce the error because my document is quite large now, with many packages loaded.

Hope however you can help me, maybe explaining me the solution proposed by TextStudio!

Thanks, 
Giovanni

Edit: I tried to hack down the document. I have noticed that the error is in definition of the list of symbols or in the definition of the symbols (even if this is strange because until the day before yesterday it worked). The example for the table is from here [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units), but if you know a better way to get the list of symbols (without errors) please let it me know. I have noticed that on my PC this script gives me the error, but If I copy and paste it in a new file (even without saving it) the error does not appear. So I have tried to delete .gls, . toc and . aux files but the error remains. I Hope however this is sufficient for solving the problem! Thanks!

```
% A Classic Thesis Style
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fix some latex issues see: http://texdoc.net      /texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf
\documentclass {scrreprt} % Classe: Report

\PassOptionsToPackage{parts,%drafting,%
listings,floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
subfig,eulerchapternumbers,beramono,eulermath,%dottedtoc,
pdfspacing} 
{classicthesis}   
\usepackage{classicthesis}                                      

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Encoding inputs
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel} % Select language (last most used)               
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics

\usepackage{newunicodechar} % For copy%paste from PDF or web (citations)
\newunicodechar{ﬁ}{fi}
\newunicodechar{ﬀ}{ff}

\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\usepackage{csquotes} % Context Sensitive Quotation Facilities

\usepackage{mathtools}

% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions

\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
   \newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{multirow} % single row for multiple columns in tables

\usepackage{caption} % Ita: didascalie
\captionsetup{font=small} % format=hang,
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{cleveref} % many references to tables

% Glossary, list of symbols and nomenclature

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,acronym,xindy]{glossaries} 
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols} % create add. symbolslist

 \glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit} {\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit} % Inserts unit column

 \makeglossaries

 % SYMBOLS
 \newglossaryentry{departures}{name=\ensuremath{D},
 description={Set of departing flights (departures)},
 unit={[-]},
 type=symbolslist}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
    \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
    \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
    \hline
    \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
    & \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

% List of symbols
\glsaddall
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because of missing MWE only a suggestion: Remove the auxiliary files like `.aux` and `.toc` and `.gls` and try again.

Comment: Note that - as far as I remember - there are some glossary styles conflict with the `classicthesis` documentclass. A short search of the glossaries manual might help.

Comment: The page number xxvii suggests a reference in the front matter. Can you [hack down](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html) your document to reproduce just that page?

Comment: I have added the document hacked down. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Guys I have found the error: I declared a symbol as " u_^a" instead of "u_f^a". Thanks however to all!