# Add third column to acronym

Tags: acronyms

I am using the `acronym`package for acronyms, symbols and constants in my report. I would like the list of constants to be slightly different than the other two lists. I want to use the `\acroextra{}` macro to add the value of the constants and to print them in a third column.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\large \textbf{Symbols}
\begin{acronym}[longest]
\acro{lam}[$\lambda$]{wavelength}
\acro{temp}[$T$]{Temperature}
\end{acronym}

\large \textbf{Constants}
\begin{acronym}[longest]
\acro{c}[$c$]{speed of light \acroextra{299 792 458 m/s}}
\acro{sig}[$\sigma$]{Stefan–Boltzmann constant \acroextra{$5.670367 10^{-8}$ W/(m$^2$K$^4$)}}
\end{acronym}

\vspace{1in}

Some text and acro calls
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: Original]

I would like it result in something like this:

[image: Wanted]

Can I make this work with a second width in the environment (`\begin{acronym}[longest short][longest long]`) or something? The values could also be right aligned if that is simpler.

Comment: This would be quite easy with `glossaries` ...

Comment: The difficulty here is that `acronym` uses a `description` environment with the short form as the optional argument to `\item`.  You'd need to rewrite this in a tabular.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought it might be, and was just looking.  If so that would certainly be less work than rewriting a chunk of `acronym`

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, using `long3col`  style for example and using the `symbol` key etc. But the O.P. would have to switch the whole style of acronym definition

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I reckon a large part of that could be automated, but haven't looked at it in any depth

Comment: @ChrisH: Here's a list of symbols with unit specification with glossaries: The adaption to use values is quite straightforward, I would say. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units

Comment: Right aligned symbols can easily achived with `\hfill` before `\acroextra{`, but from my point of view thats not an optimal solution.

Comment: @Bobyandbob perhaps in a minipage it would be better (still right-aligned but to a more sensible place).

Comment: @Bobyandbob your answer is better anyway

Comment: If your questions is answered you could [accept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer to close("marked as solved") the quesion. Or do you need further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\makebox[width][position]{text}` command. The box contains your constants names. The width of the box is specified by the optional `width` argument. With `position` you can specify the position of text within the box with `l` (flushleft), `r`(flushright),... . The values can be placed after the box. For easier handling i put the box inside a newcommand like this:

```
\newcommand{\acrosecondcolumn}[1]{
      \acroextra{\makebox[55mm][l]{#1}}
    }
```

**Example entry:**

```
\acro{c}[A]{\acrosecondcolumn{B}C}
```

1.column: A ---whitespace--- 2.column: B ---whitespace--- 3.column: C

**Solution:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{acronym}

\newcommand{\acrosecondcolumn}[1]{
  \acroextra{\makebox[55mm][l]{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\large \textbf{Symbols}
\begin{acronym}[longest]
\acro{lam}[$\lambda$]{wavelength}
\acro{temp}[$T$]{Temperature}
\end{acronym}

\large \textbf{Constants}
\begin{acronym}[longest]
\acro{c}[A]{\acrosecondcolumn{B}C}
\acro{c}[$c$]{\acrosecondcolumn{speed of light}299 792 458 m/s}
\acro{sig}[$\sigma$]{\acrosecondcolumn{Stefan–Boltzmann constant}$5.670367 10^{-8}$ W/(m$^2$K$^4$)}
\end{acronym}
\vspace{1in}
Some text and acro calls
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `glossaries` package, which is a little bit more powerful than `acronym` considering its configurability and features.

Here, a new glossary with a special `symbolvalue` key is defined, it is a variation of my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269571/31729) to a similar question.

Make sure to run in this order (assuming the document is called `foo.tex`)

1. pdflatex foo
2. makeglossaries foo
3. pdflatex foo

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{symbolvalue}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrysymbolvalue}{\GLsentrysymbolvalue}{\glssymbolvalue}{\Glssymbolvalue}{\GLSsymbolvalue}
\glssetnoexpandfield{symbolvalue}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
\newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
  description={Geometrical symbol},
  symbolvalue={},
  type=symbolslist
}

\newglossaryentry{planck}{
  name=\ensuremath{h},
  description={Planck's constant},
  symbolvalue={\SI{6,6d-34}{\joule\second}},
  type=symbolslist
}

\newglossaryentry{lightspeed}{
  name=\ensuremath{c},
  description={Speed of light},
  symbolvalue={\SI{299792432}{\meter/\second}},
  type=symbolslist
}





\newglossarystyle{symbsymbolvaluelong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Value \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
  & \glssymbolvalue{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbsymbolvaluelong]   % list of symbols
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I make multiple lists of glossaries, as this is a vital function to my application?

Comment: When I run the example you gave I just get a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kajsa: I don't know what you have done so your question is difficult to answer