# glossaries: No printed glossaries when switching to \makenoidxglossaries

Tags: glossaries

As a follow-up to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269571/2288), replacing `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossary` with `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary` results in a white page without printed glossaries. What is missing here?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}                           % documentclass: scrbook
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makenoidxglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
    \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
        description={Geometrical value},
        unit={},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
        description={Height of tower},
        unit={\si{m}},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{energyconsump}{name=\ensuremath{P},
        description={Energy consumption},
        unit={\si{kW}},
        type=symbolslist}




% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST ========================================
    \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR MAIN GLOSSARY ========================================
    \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall

    \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols
    \printnoidxglossary[type=main]                     % main glossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need a `sort` value for all your symbols or use `sort=use` or `sort=def` in the symbols list. (I don't recommend switching to `\makenoidxglossaries`. Is there a particular reason for it?)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot there is no particular reason, but I just want to keep using `\makenoidxglossaries` since I already have been using it from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `glossaries` package provides three ways of sorting and collating the glossary information: using TeX ([option 1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1)), using `makeindex` ([option 2](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option2)) or using `xindy` ([option 3](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option3)). The extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) provides a fourth option ([`bib2gls`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/bib2gls/)).

These methods sort according to the value of the `sort` field. In your example, you haven't used the `sort` key in any of your definitions, so the value of the `sort` field has to be determined programmatically, but this varies according to the sorting option.

In the case of `makeindex` or `xindy` (`\makeglossaries`), the sort value is obtained by copying the `name` value *and then sanitizing it*. This means that, for example, where you have

```
name=\ensuremath{P}
```

the sort field becomes the sequence of characters `\` `e` `n` `s` `u` `r` `e` `m` `a` `t` `h` `{` `P` `}` so when the information is written to the external file read by `makeindex` / `xindy` no expansion occurs.

When using TeX to sort (`\makenoidxglossaries`) the sanitization is switched off. This method uses a very primitive comparison and is designed just for words not symbols. Now when the sort field is constructed, the value is copied over from the `name`, but it expands as the field value is set. Before this expansion occurs, standard diacritic commands (such as `\"`) are temporarily redefined to effectively strip accents to allow for a simple ASCII comparison.

For example, if you have

```
name = {\'{e}lite}
```

then

- with `makeindex` the sort value is the sequence of characters `\` `'` `{` `e` `}` `l` `i` `t` `e` which `makeindex` will put in the "Symbols" letter group (since it starts with a backslash), not in the more intuitively obvious "E" letter group;
- with `xindy` the sort value is written to the file as `\'{e}lite` but `xindy` is intelligent enough to strip commands and braces, so the sort value effectively becomes `elite`;
- with TeX the sort value loses the accent commands during the expansion that occurs when the `sort` field is set, so the sort value becomes `elite`.

The `\makenoidxglossaries` method isn't suitable for sorting symbols (such as `\ensuremath{P}`) when the default word-ordering setting is on because of this expansion. The other methods aren't particularly suitable for sorting symbols using word order either: `makeindex` is the most tolerant (but the resulting order may look strange); `xindy` will fail on symbols like `\ensuremath{\pi}`.

If you have entries that represent symbols rather than words then you need to explicitly set the `sort` value, for example:

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
    sort={pi},
    description={Geometrical value},
    unit={},
    type=symbolslist}
```

or use a different sorting rule or sanitize the sort value (using the `sanitizesort` package option).

The `glossaries-extra` package, when used with the `symbols` package option, provides `\glsxtrnewsymbol` which automatically sets the `sort` to the *label* (which can't have special characters anyway). The `symbols` package option automatically creates a glossary with the label `symbols`, so

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Geometrical value},
    unit={},
    type=symbolslist]{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi}}
```

is equivalent to

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
    sort={symb:Pi},
    type={symbols},
    category={symbol},
    description={Geometrical value},
    unit={}}
```

(The `category` key is only available with the extension package.)

If you really want to use `\makenoidxglossaries` (although I don't recommend it, as it's much slower), here are your possible options:

1. Explicitly use the `sort` key when defining the symbols:

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

   \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist}

   \makenoidxglossaries % use TeX to sort

   \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
     sort={pi},
     description={Geometrical value},
     type=symbolslist}

   \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
     sort={h},
     description={Height of tower},
     type=symbolslist}

   \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}

   \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}

   \begin{document}

   \glsaddall

   \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=main]

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use the `sanitizesort` package option.

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \usepackage[acronym,toc,sanitizesort]{glossaries}

   \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist}

   \makenoidxglossaries % use TeX to sort

   \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
     description={Geometrical value},
     type=symbolslist}

   \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
     description={Height of tower},
     type=symbolslist}

   \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}

   \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some
   description}}

   \begin{document}

   \glsaddall

   \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=main]

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Change the sort rule to either `def` or `use` for the symbols. This method is faster as no actual sorting occurs with this rule. (The main and acronyms glossaries will still be sorted.)

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

   \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist}

   \makenoidxglossaries % use TeX to sort

   \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
     description={Geometrical value},
     type=symbolslist}

   \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
     description={Height of tower},
     type=symbolslist}

   \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}

   \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}

   \begin{document}

   \glsaddall

   \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist,sort=use]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=main]

   \end{document}
   ```
4. Use `\glsxtrnewsymbol` with the `glossaries-extra` package (or provide a similar command). Note that switching to `glossaries-extra` requires the abbreviation style to be set for the acronyms to `long-short` if you want to replicate the style used in the above.

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

   \makenoidxglossaries % use TeX to sort

   \glsxtrnewsymbol
     [description={Geometrical value}]
     {symb:Pi}{\ensuremath{\pi}}

   \glsxtrnewsymbol
     [description={Height of tower}]
     {height}{\ensuremath{h}}

   \setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

   \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}

   \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}

   \begin{document}

   \glsaddall

   \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,title={Symbolslist}]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=main]

   \end{document}
   ```

For comparison, here's a `bib2gls` version which sorts the symbols according to the description, the abbreviations according to the short form and the regular terms according to the name:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{symbols.bib}
@symbol{symb:Pi,
  name={\ensuremath{\pi}},
  description={Geometrical value}
}

@symbol{height,
  name={\ensuremath{h}},
  description={Height of tower}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviations.bib}
@acronym{VRBD,
  short={VRBD},
  long={Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{entries.bib}
@entry{Biofouling,
  name={Biofouling},
  description={Some description}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record,acronym,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={symbols},% data in symbols.bib
  type=symbols,% put these entries in the 'symbols' glossary
  selection={all},% select all entries in .bib file
% sort @symbol entries by 'description' if 'sort' field missing:
  symbol-sort-fallback={description}
]

% style must be set before relevant \GlsXtrLoadResources:
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={abbreviations},% data in abbreviations.bib
  type=acronym,% put these entries in the 'acronym' glossary
  selection={all},% select all entries in .bib file
% sort @acronym entries by 'short' if 'sort' field missing:
  abbreviation-sort-fallback={short}
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries},% data in entries.bib
  type=main,% put these entries in the 'main' glossary
  selection={all}% select all entries in .bib file
]

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

If the document is called `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Or if you want letter groups:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The symbols are ordered according to the description:

[image: Symbols π Geometrical value h Height of tower]

I can change this to order according to the Unicode values of `h` (0x0068) and `π` (0x03C0):

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={symbols},% data in symbols.bib
  type=symbols,% put these entries in the 'symbols' glossary
  selection={all},% select all entries in .bib file
% sort @symbol entries by 'name' if 'sort' field missing:
  symbol-sort-fallback={name},
  sort=letter-nocase% case-insensitive letter sort
]
```

[image: Symbols h Height of tower π Geometrical value]

Comment: This is an encyclopedic answer which I need to go through it attentively. I highly appreciate the effort and time you took.