# Latex glossaries greek symbols: not in alphabetical order

Tags: glossaries, greek

I am writing a thesis, I have a List of Greek Symbols chapter. The list can be successfully generated, but I found the sequence of greek symbols were not correct. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % hyperlinks
\usepackage[toc, nopostdot, nonumberlist, nogroupskip, acronym, order=letter]{glossaries} 

\newglossary[ch1]{greekstyle}{ch2}{ch3}{List of Greek Symbols}

\setglossarystyle{long} % left align
\makeglossaries


\include{glossary_entries} % define all your symbols in a separated file. 


\title{My title}
\author{Name}
\date{November 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% print all the symbols without referencing them
\glsaddall
% remove the left vacant space of long style
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{1.0\hsize}

\printglossary[title=List of Symbols]


\printglossary[type=greekstyle]

\section{Introduction}
Some words...

\end{document}
```

My `glossary_entries.tex` file:

```
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}


% greek -------------------------------------------------------
\newglossaryentry{gls:phi}{name={$\phi_i, \phi_n$},description={basis function, orthogonal basis functions}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:tau}{name={$\tau$},description={truncation error}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:delta}{name={$\delta_{i, j}$},description={Kronecker delta}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:psi}{name={$\psi$},description={intermediate term in barycentric Lagrange interpolation}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Omega}{name={$\Omega$},description={element representation, computational domain}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Omega_e}{name={$\Omega_e$},description={domain of element $e$}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:lambda}{name={$\lambda, \lambda_i $},description={eigenvalue}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Lambda}{name={$\Lambda$},description={diagonal matrix of coefficient matrix $\mathbf{A}$}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:xi}{name={$\xi$},description={reference space coordinate in $x$ direction}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:eta}{name={$\eta$},description={reference space coordinate in $y$ direction}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:sigma}{name={$\sigma$},description={error decay rate}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:alpha}{name={$\alpha$},description={the offset of linear least squares best fit}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:beta}{name={$\beta$},description={the slope of linear least squares best fit}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:estimated_error}{name={$\epsilon_{est}$},description={estimated error}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:discretization_tol}{name={$\epsilon$},description={discretization tolerance, balance ratio}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Xi}{name={$\Xi$},description={mortar element}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Psi}{name={$\Psi$},description={solution projection on the mortar}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Phi}{name={$\Phi$},description={numerical flux on mortar}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:Gamma}{name={$\Gamma $},description={adjacent vertices set, domain boundary}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:test_function}{name={$\varphi, \varphi_j$},description={test function}, type=greekstyle}
```

What it generates:
[image: prom_fig]

But this is not in alphabetical order. For example `\Xi` should be placed before `\Omega` . The uppercase order and the lowercase order are both wrong. How can I fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, take a look to this post> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404724/unusual-sorting-of-greek-letters-and-math-mode-symbols-when-using-glossaries-pac

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy fix: arrange the Greek letters manually.

One can add a `sort` argument to the `\newglossaryentry{}`. I numbered my greek letters in `glossary_entries.tex` like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{gls:phi}{name={$\phi_i, \phi_n$},description={basis function, orthogonal basis functions}, sort = {b21}, type=greekstyle}

\newglossaryentry{gls:tau}{name={$\tau$},description={truncation error}, sort = {b19}, type=greekstyle}

...
```

And changed the command to print glossaries:

```
\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard, type=greekstyle]
```

Then I obtained the desired order.