# Sorting an Acronym entry with \mathcal{} with Glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, mathcal

I'm using the `glossaries` package for my list of acronyms with the following options:

```
\usepackage[acronyms,nopostdot,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nomain,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{MyGlossary.tex}
```

and in the `MyGlossary.tex` I have the following entry:

```
\newacronym{np}{$\mathcal{NP}$}{Nondeterministic polynomial time}
```

Unfortunately, when I print the list with the following lines,

```
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=!, labelwidth=7em}
\printglossary[title=List of Abbreviations and Acronyms, type=\acronymtype]
```

it puts said entry at the top of the list, before "A", and not to "N".
I kow that the `glossaries` package has the `sort={}` option for glossary entries. However, I couldn't find anything similar for acronyms in the glossaries manual.

Is there a quick fix option for this within `glossaries`, or do I have to switch to another package?
I know this is not 100% the intended use of the acronym finction, but I'd like to make it work anyways.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question goes into some detail about sorting items that aren't just ordinary text: [Unusual sorting of greek letters and math mode symbols when using glossaries package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404724)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `sort=...` to the optional agrument of `\newacronym`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms,nopostdot,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nomain,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[sort=np]{np}{$\mathcal{NP}$}{Nondeterministic polynomial time}
\newacronym{nq}{NQ}{NQ long form}
\newacronym{no}{NO}{NO long form}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[title=List of Abbreviations and Acronyms, type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

---

From the `glossaries` documentation:

```
\newacronym[〈key-val list〉]{〈label〉}{〈abbrv〉}{〈long〉}
```

> The optional argument `{〈key-val list〉}` allows you to specify additional information. Any `key` that can be used in the second argument of `\newglossaryentry` can also be used here in `〈key-val list〉`.

Comment: Ouch, it didn't come to my mind to at least first just try... Thanks heaps!