# Abbreviation list not sorted alphabetically

Tags: glossaries, sorting

I have this list of abbreviations and everything works fine except for pcrs and ip3. I tried to change `\ce{IP3}` to `ip3` but it doesn't change place. I also tried to change or erase `pcrs` but I get an error and I get an empty line. Can someone help me with these exceptions to make my list alphabetically ordered?

List part 1:
[image: list part 1]

list part 2:
[image: list part 2]

when trying to remove pcr:
[image: when trying to remove pcr]

```
\usepackage{dissertation}

\begin{document}

% ACRONYMS -----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Acronyms}

\loadglsentries{"../references/acronyms.tex"}
\makeglossaries


\newacronym{t2r}{T2R}{taste receptor protein type 2}
\newacronym{gpcr}{GPCR}{G protein-coupled receptor}
\newacronym{Tas2r}{Tas2r}{taste receptor gene type 2}
\newacronym{TAS1R}{TAS1R}{taste receptor gene type 1}
\newacronym{TAS2R}{TAS2R}{taste receptor gene type 2}
\newacronym{tm}{TM}{transmembrane}
\newacronym{grafs}{GRAFS}{Glutamate, Rhodopsin, Adhesion, Frizzled/Taste2, Secretin}
\newacronym{moe}{MOE}{main olfactory epithelium}
\newacronym{vno}{VNO}{vomeronasal organ}
\newacronym{or}{OR}{olfactory receptors}
\newacronym{vrs}{VRs}{vomeronasal receptors}
\newacronym{v1r}{V1R}{vomeronasal receptors type-1}
\newacronym{v2r}{V2R}{vomeronasal receptors type-2}
\newacronym{trc}{TRC}{taste receptor cells}
\newacronym{hugo}{HUGO}{Human Genome Organization}
\newacronym{mgd}{MGD}{Mouse Genome Database}
\newacronym{t1r}{T1R}{taste receptors proteins type 1}
\newacronym{dag}{DAG}{diacylglycerol}
\newacronym{pip2}{PIP2}{phosphatidylinositol 4,5-bisphosphate}
\newacronym{trpm5}{TRPM5}{transient receptor potential cation channel subfamily M member 5}
\newacronym{pde}{PDE}{phosphodiesterase}
\newacronym{camp}{cAMP}{cyclic adenosine monophosphate}
\newacronym{cgmp}{cGMP}{cyclic guanosine monophosphate}
\newacronym{cnmps}{cNMP}{cyclic nucleotide}
\newacronym{ptc}{PTC}{phenylthiocarbamide}
\newacronym{dxm}{DXM}{dextromethorphan}
\newacronym{pop}{POP}{6-n-propyl-2-thiouracil}
\newacronym{sccs}{SCCs}{solitary chemosensory cells}
\newacronym{plc}{PLC$\beta$2}{phospholipase C $\beta$2}
\newacronym{pmn}{PMN}{polymorphonuclear}
\newacronym{tes}{TEs}{transposable elements}
\newacronym{lines}{LINEs}{long interspersed elements}
\newacronym{cr1}{CR1}{chicken repeat 1}
\newacronym{sines}{SINEs}{short interspersed elements}
\newacronym{fa}{FA}{fatty acids}
\newacronym{hsps}{HSPs}{High-Scoring Segment Pairs}
\newacronym{fsm}{FSM}{finite state machine}
\newacronym{blast}{BLAST}{Basic Local Alignment Search Tool}
\newacronym{ncbi}{NCBI}{National Center for Biotechnology Information}
\newacronym{msa}{MSA}{multiple sequence analysis}
\newacronym{mega}{MEGA}{Molecular Evolutionary Genetics Analysis}
\newacronym{aic}{AIC}{Akaike information criteria}
\newacronym{bic}{BIC}{Bayesian information criteria}
\newacronym{dlrt}{dLRT}{dynamical likelihood ratio tests}
\newacronym{hlrt}{hLRT}{hierarchical likelihood ratio tests}
\newacronym{dt}{DT}{decision theory method}
\newacronym{mcmc}{MCMC}{Markov chain Monte Carlo}
\newacronym{paml}{PAML}{Phylogenetic Analysis by Maximum Likelihood}
\newacronym{pss}{PSS}{positive selected sites}
\newacronym{meme}{MEME}{Mixed Effects Model of Evolution}
\newacronym{fel}{FEL}{Fixed Effects Likelihood}
\newacronym{fubar}{FUBAR}{Fast Unconstrained Bayesian AppRoximation}
\newacronym{slac}{SLAC}{Single-Likelihood Ancestor Counting}
\newacronym{pdb}{PDB}{Protein Data Bank}
\newacronym{vmd}{VMD}{Visual Molecular Dynamics}
\newacronym{ide}{IDE}{Integrated Development Environment}
\newacronym{ml}{ML}{maximum likelihood}
\newacronym{ip3}{\ce{IP3}}{inositol 1,4,5-triphosphate}
\newacronym{iss}{ISS}{index score}
\newacronym{issc}{ISS.C}{index critical score}
\newacronym{gtr}{GTR}{General Time Reversible Model}
\newacronym{hky}{HKY}{Hasegawa, Kishino, and Yano Model}
\newacronym{absrel}{aBSREL}{adaptive Branch-Site Random Effects Likelihood}
\newacronym{beb}{BEB}{Bayes empirical Bayes}
\newacronym{bi}{BI}{Bayesian Inference}
\newacronym{busted}{BUSTED}{Branch-site Unrestricted Statistical Test for Episodic Diversification}
\newacronym{gard}{GARD}{Genetic Algorithm for Recombination Detection}
\newacronym{dn}{d$N$}{non-synonymous substitutions per non-synonymous sites}
\newacronym{ds}{d$S$}{synonymous substitutions per synonymous sites}
\newacronym{omega}{$\omega$}{nonsynonymous/synonymous rate ratio}
\newacronym{lrt}{LRT}{likelihood ratio tests}
\newacronym{nss}{NSS}{negative selected sites}
\newacronym{otus}{OTUs}{operational taxonomic units}
\newacronym{tm5}{TM5}{fifth transmembrane}
\newacronym{hot}{HoT}{heads-or-tails}
\newacronym{pcrs}{RT-PCR}{reverse transcription-polymerase chain reaction}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a compilable example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Nobody has your `dissertation` package, by the way.

Comment: The reason that "IP3" is listed first is because the sort argument begins with `\ce`, which will sort before the regular alphabetical listing.  This argument needs a separate sort field; I don't know offhand how to provide that.  Similarly "RT-PCR" has a sort field `pcrs` so it will sort with "P".  Look for items where the sort field is different from the string to be listed.

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` again? Because if you change the name of an entry and recompile, the name will change but the ordering will not. Running `makeglossaries` takes care of the alphabetical sorting.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571824/134144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
\newacronym{ip3}{IP$_3$}{inositol 1,4,5-triphosphate}
```

or

```
\newacronym{ip3}{IP\textsubscript{3}}{inositol 1,4,5-triphosphate}
```

if you want the subscript to be bold.

Comment: The first example doesn't work. There is one `}` to much ...