# Non-Main Glossaries Not Compiling on TexShop (Mac)

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, texshop

I am trying to create a latex file with multiple glossaries. After several attempts at debugging it appears that the problem is something to do with TeXShop on the mac. Specifically I have tried code below (which was gotten from https://texblog.org/2014/04/01/multiple-glossaries-in-latex/). When I compile it in Overleaf everything seems to work fine. However when I compile it on my local TexShop (v 4.66 on Mac) using either pdflatexmk or lualatexmk only the main glossary appears.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

%Alternative glossary for top-level domains
\newglossary[tlg]{domain}{tld}{tdn}{Top-Level Domains}

% Generate glossaries
\makeglossaries

\begin{document} 

\section{Top-level domains}

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{gls:tld}{name=TLD, description={List of top-level domains}}

\newglossaryentry{tld:com}{type=domain, name=.com, description={Commercial entities}}
\newglossaryentry{tld:net}{type=domain, name=.net, description={Network infrastructure}}
\newglossaryentry{tld:org}{type=domain, name=.org, description={Public interest registry}}

% Use the terms
Top-level domains (\gls{gls:tld}) include \gls{tld:com}, \gls{tld:net}, and \gls{tld:org}.

% Print the glossaries
\printglossary[type=domain]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to enclose the names of the domains in additional curly brackets, so e.g. `name={.com} `? This way the dot should be recognized as part of the name if I am not mistaken. For further investigation the exact error message could be helpful!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the issue as (1) I have used other entries with pure text and had the same problem (I was just using this one as I found  it online so I knew someone else had also gotten it to work)  (2) it seemed to work fine in overleaf.

Comment: I have tested you code with TeXShop 4.66 on macOs 11.5 and the result is the same than overleaf's. I have added an engine to TeXShop for glossaries following [this guide](https://dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/index.shtml#texshop) and compile using this engine

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I use

```
\makenoidxglossaries \
\printnoidxglossary
```

instead of

```
\makeglossaries\
\printglossary
```

the non-main glossaries are displayed in TeXShop.

I still do not understand why this should be the case, nor why things worked in Overleaf though.

Comment: Just saw this link, maybe the answer there can help you: 'https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389875/glossaries-no-printed-glossaries-when-switching-to-makenoidxglossaries' Apparently it may has happen because of the missing sort field, I don't knot how Overleaf handles it (might be another option mentioned in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting… The latexmk based engines for TeXShop are set up for use with the old glossary package and simple uses of the glossaries package. For more complicated use please download the `TeXShop latexmk and advanced glossaries package use.zip` file from https://herbs.github.io. There are instructions on how to install the changes and what has to be done to create a platexmkrc file for the custom glossaries in your project. These changes remove the compatibility with the old glossary package and there is a supplied platexmkrc file to restore that compatibility if needed.

Once the changes have been made here is an example platexmkrc file that will use those changes for one of the glossaries package sample files:

```
 # custom dependencies for glossary-lipsum-examples.tex
 add_cus_dep('glo2', 'gls2', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo3', 'gls3', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo4', 'gls4', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo5', 'gls5', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo6', 'gls6', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo7', 'gls7', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo8', 'gls8', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo9', 'gls9', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('glo10', 'gls10', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
 add_cus_dep('slo', 'sls', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
```