# Using both bold and non-bold symbols in glossaries symbol list

Tags: symbols, glossaries

I am using glossaries for creating lists of acronyms and symbols. For the list of symbols including units, I use code from this answer by Christian Hupfer: [glossaries: How to customize list of symbols with additional column for units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units?newreg=4293a221ec3b4b1a8f7d97f7868a098a)

However, I need to differ between bold and non-bold symbols (referring to tensors or scalars), which is apparently not possible with that code. I'm struggling with the code adjustment pretty much and I could not find any way to make that possible. Could somebody help me out, please? Thanks a lot!!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}                           
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-    package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
\newglossaryentry{sig}{name=\ensuremath{\sigma},
    description={This is a non-bold stress scalar},
    unit={\si{\mega\pascal}},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{csig}{name=\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\sigma}},
    description={This is a bold Cauchy stress tensor},
    unit={\si{\mega\pascal}},
    type=symbolslist}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST     ========================================
\newacronym{frp}{FRP}{Fiber Reinforced Polymers}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centeringarraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of     symbols

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example doesn't compile without errors. When using siunitx commands in glossary entry you should disable expansion of the glossary fields with `\glsnoexpandfields` or (not really recommended as it has other issues)  move the definition behind \begin{document} as siunitx does a lot initialization only a `\begin{document}`. Beside this you have typo (a missing backslash). If I correct the errors the bold symbols work fine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-    package




% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST     ========================================
\newacronym{frp}{FRP}{Fiber Reinforced Polymers}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}
\glsnoexpandfields
% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================


\newglossaryentry{sig}{name=\ensuremath{\sigma},
    description={This is a non-bold stress scalar},
    unit={\si{\mega\pascal}},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{csig}{name=\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\sigma}},
    description={This is a bold Cauchy stress tensor},
    unit={\si{\mega\pascal}},
    type=symbolslist}

    \begin{document}
    \glsaddall

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of     symbols

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [I really don't recommend putting the definitions in the `document` environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs). (Unless you use `\usepackage[docdef=restricted]{glossaries-extra}` and have all the glossaries at the end of the document.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I understand the problems. But if glossaries expands everything by default the preamble isn't a good place either ;-). Why doesn't glossaries use `\glsnoexpandfields` by default?

Comment: Thanks you very much Ulrike for your fast Response. There were some copy-paste-mistakes done by myself which hid the actual Problem: using the \usepackage{mathptmx} impeded the bold symbols. Is there a suitable alternative to mathptmx? Furthermore, does \glsnoexpandfields Need to be at a certain Location when the definitions are put in the preamble? Thanks!

Comment: Load the bm package. And next time you ask a question test the example before posting and so avoid to waste the time of the helpers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Historical reasons. I can't change it now or it will affect existing documents that programatically define entries. With the new `glossaries-extra`+`bib2gls` method, `\glsnoexpandfields` is implemented by default.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks and, well, you're right, sorry for that!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I edited the answer to reflect the discussion.