# How to make a custom list of symbols with separated greek and roman symbols?

Tags: symbols, lists, glossaries, units

I am using the glossaries package to make a list of acronyms and a list of symbols (separately). Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457925/glossaries-how-to-add-a-column-for-the-page-of-definition-first-appearance-of-s) approach, I tried to make a list of symbols that has that layout, but with a separated greek and roman symbols section.

I tried to do this using the link's `\newglossarystyle` command:

```latex
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long4col-booktabs}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
     \begin{longtable}{cp{\glsdescwidth}c>{\centering}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries \descriptionname & \bfseries Unit & \bfseries First appearance \tabularnewline
    \midrule\endhead}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1}  & \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryunit{##1} 
        \tabularnewline
    }%
}
```

This gives me a push in the right direction in that the separation of roman and greek letters is correct. However, the units column and symbols column, except for the *Roman letters* and *Greek letters* indicators, are left entirely empty. 
[image: The output of the symbols glossary, with separated Roman and Greek letters, but with the units and symbols missing or mixed up.]

Taken from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244923/converting-a-nomenclature-example-to-use-glossaries), I have defined the `unit` key using this command, before calling `\makeglossaries`:

```latex
\glsaddkey
{unit}          % new key
{\relax}        % default value if "unit" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
{\glsentryunit} % analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentryunit} % analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsunit}      % analogous to \glstext
{\Glsunit}      % analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSunit}      % analogous to \GLStext
```

I have made the distinction between Roman and Greek symbols by assigning a `parent` to each glossary entry, following [this approach](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14473):

```latex
% Define the parent romand and greek symbols
\newglossaryentry{romanletter}{name={\textbf{Roman letters}}, description={\nopostdesc}, sort={1}, type=symbols}
\newglossaryentry{greekletter}{name={\textbf{Greek letters}}, description={\nopostdesc}, sort={2}, type=symbols}

% Don't expand the unit field 
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

% Some sample symbol glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{drag}{name={\ensuremath{D}},
                     sort={drag},
                     description={drag},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\newton}}}
\newglossaryentry{h}{name={\ensuremath{h}},
                     sort={h},
                     description={altitude},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\metre}}}
\newglossaryentry{lift}{name={\ensuremath{L}},
                     sort={lift},
                     description={lift},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\newton}}}
\newglossaryentry{mach}{name={\ensuremath{M}},
                     sort={Mach number},
                     description={Mach number},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={[-]}}
\newglossaryentry{mass}{name={\ensuremath{m}},
                     sort={mass},
                     description={mass},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\kilogram}}}
\newglossaryentry{pitchrate}{name={\ensuremath{q}},
                     sort={q},
                     description={pitch rate},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\radian\per\second}}}
% Some greek letter
\newglossaryentry{eta}{name={\ensuremath{\eta}},
                        sort={7},
                        description={(propulsive) efficiency},
                        parent={greekletter}, 
                        type={symbols},
                        unit={[-]}}
```

I am probably going wrong somewhere in the `\newglossarystyle` command, but I've been trying to work it out reading the [docs](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) and inspecting previously posted questions, but I can't seem to work it out. I find the syntax `\renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1}  & \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryunit{##1}` quite confusing and am not able to work out all those commands from the glossaries docs.

Summarising all the above in a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx} \sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, nogroupskip, nomain, indexonlyfirst, acronym, symbols, style=long4col, stylemods={longbooktabs}]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{page~}{pages~}

\glsaddkey
{unit}          % new key
{\relax}        % default value if "unit" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
{\glsentryunit} % analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentryunit} % analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsunit}      % analogous to \glstext
{\Glsunit}      % analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSunit}      % analogous to \GLStext

\makeglossaries

% Define the parent romand and greek symbols
\newglossaryentry{romanletter}{name={\textbf{Roman letters}}, description={\nopostdesc}, sort={1}, type=symbols}
\newglossaryentry{greekletter}{name={\textbf{Greek letters}}, description={\nopostdesc}, sort={2}, type=symbols}

% Don't expand the unit field 
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

% Some sample symbol glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{drag}{name={\ensuremath{D}},
                     sort={drag},
                     description={drag},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\newton}}}
\newglossaryentry{h}{name={\ensuremath{h}},
                     sort={h},
                     description={altitude},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\metre}}}
\newglossaryentry{lift}{name={\ensuremath{L}},
                     sort={lift},
                     description={lift},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\newton}}}
\newglossaryentry{mach}{name={\ensuremath{M}},
                     sort={Mach number},
                     description={Mach number},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={[-]}}
\newglossaryentry{mass}{name={\ensuremath{m}},
                     sort={mass},
                     description={mass},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\kilogram}}}
\newglossaryentry{pitchrate}{name={\ensuremath{q}},
                     sort={q},
                     description={pitch rate},
                     parent={romanletter},
                     type={symbols},
                     unit={\si{\radian\per\second}}}
% Some greek letter
\newglossaryentry{eta}{name={\ensuremath{\eta}},
                        sort={7},
                        description={(propulsive) efficiency},
                        parent={greekletter}, 
                        type={symbols},
                        unit={[-]}}

% Set the new glossary style
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long4col-booktabs}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
     \begin{longtable}{cp{\glsdescwidth}c>{\centering}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries \descriptionname & \bfseries Unit & \bfseries First appearance \tabularnewline
    \midrule\endhead}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1}  & \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryunit{##1} 
        \tabularnewline
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=symbunitlong]

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I would also like each column's width to be adapted to the widest entry in that column. For example, the last column should be made wider to display **First appearance** in one line. Moreover, the entries should be left-aligned instead of centered. This is of secondary importance, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okaaaay ... i'm no expert in glossary styles, so i tried my best.

First of all your biggest mistake was not to use the full possibilities of the `glossaries-extra` package ^_~ See this [link](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/#longextra) for more, but take your awe & time because you will need it. That aside, there you will find the `longextra` stylemod as well as the `long-loc-sym-desc-name` style. It is a perfect start for your style choice.

By defining a symbol using the `symbol` key you have everything you need for the style modification. I copied most of it from the original style file (after package installation: MiKTeX->tex->latex->glossaries-extra). Last but not least define your column order and of course the use of the `unit` key.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}    \sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, nogroupskip, nomain, indexonlyfirst, acronym, symbols, style=long4col, stylemods={longextra}]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{page~}{pages~}

\glsaddkey
{unit}          % new key
{\relax}        % default value if "unit" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
{\glsentryunit} % analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentryunit} % analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsunit}      % analogous to \glstext
{\Glsunit}      % analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSunit}      % analogous to \GLStext

\makeglossaries

% Define the parent roman and greek symbols
\newglossaryentry{romanletter}{
    name={\textbf{Roman letters}},
    description={\nopostdesc}, 
    sort={1}, 
    type=symbols,
}
\newglossaryentry{greekletter}{
    name={\textbf{Greek letters}},
    description={\nopostdesc}, 
    sort={2}, 
    type=symbols,
}

% Don't expand the unit field 
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

% Some sample symbol glossary entry with roman letter ...
\newglossaryentry{mass}{
    name={mass},
    symbol={\ensuremath{m}},
    unit={\si{\kilogram}},
    description={mass},
    parent={romanletter},
    type={symbols},
    sort={mass},
}
% ... and also with some greek letter
\newglossaryentry{eta}{
    name={eta},
    symbol={\ensuremath{\eta}},
    unit={[-]},
    description={(propulsive) efficiency},
    parent={greekletter}, 
    type={symbols},
    sort={eta},
}

% Inform glossary about your own key (see manual v1.41, p.60 about its original definition)
\renewcommand{\glslongextraSubNameFmt}[2]{
    \glssubentryitem{#2}\glstarget{#2}{\glsentryunit{#2}\strut}
}
% Set the new glossary style
\newglossarystyle{long-sym-desc-unit-loc}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long-loc-sym-desc-name}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
    \glspatchLToutput
    \glslongextraSymLocSetDescWidth
    \edef\@glslongextra@begintab{%
        \noexpand\begin{longtable}{%
                \expandonce\glslongextraSymbolAlign
                \expandonce\glslongextraDescAlign
                \expandonce\glslongextraNameAlign
                \expandonce\glslongextraLocationAlign
        }}%
        \@glslongextra@begintab
    }%
    {\end{longtable}
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \bfseries Symbol%
        & \bfseries \descriptionname %
        & \bfseries Unit %
        & \bfseries \mbox{1st page}%
        \tabularnewline%
        \midrule%
        \endhead%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\glslongextraGroupHeading{4}{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glslongextraNameFmt{##1} & & &%
        \tabularnewline
    }% 
    \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glslongextraSubSymbolFmt{##1}{##2} &
        \glslongextraSubDescFmt{##1}{##2} &
        \glslongextraSubNameFmt{##1}{##2} &
        \glslongextraSubLocationFmt{##1}{##2}{##3}%
        \tabularnewline
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\gls{eta} 

\Blindtext
\gls{mass}

\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long-sym-desc-unit-loc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me start by thanking you for your help, it is much appreciated! The layout of the list of symbols is exactly how I want it. However, because some of the field uses have been shuffled w.r.t. my example, using `\gls{eta}` in the main text makes the text "eta" show, instead of the symbol `\ensuremath{\eta}`. I could change this by referring to the symbol using `\glsentrysymbol{eta}`, but then the symbol appearing in the text is non-clickable and doesn't show in the list of symbols. Long story short, is there a way to make the `\gls{}` command work as it did previously?

Comment: P.S. Just changing the contents of the `name` field to the contents of the `symbol` field does the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help ... and i learned something for myself, so win-win ^_~