# list of symbols - separating greek letters

Tags: symbols, glossaries, greek, sorting

I am using a template which includes a `list of symbols` based on the `glossaries` package. The package is called as follows:

```
\RequirePackage[nonumberlist,acronym,symbols,shortcuts,toc,translate=babel]{glossaries}
```

When entering symbols, the following notation is used (one sample for `greek letters`, one for roman):

```
\newglossaryentry{A}{
name=\ensuremath{A},
description={area},
unit=m\textsuperscript{2},
sort=A,
type=symbols,
```

}

```
\newglossaryentry{tau}{
name=\ensuremath{\tau},
description={time constant},
unit=\si{\second},
sort=\tau,
type=symbols
```

}

When it comes to sorting, the `greek letter` is always on top of all roman ones because it is sorted by the special character `backslash` which comes before the A (just as all other special characters). However, I would like to have the `greek letters` below the romans - be it within a `subsection` of the LOS or simply below the entries for Z. I tried the following solution, which gave errors and did not work:
[How to make a custom list of symbols with separated greek and roman symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537607/how-to-make-a-custom-list-of-symbols-with-separated-greek-and-roman-symbols)
The LOS is included using

```
\includesymbols{LIST/symbols}
```

and in the `class`, some definitions (which I do not fully get) are made:

```
% custom symbol style
\glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}
%\glsnoexpandfields     % der macht Aerger mit \acp{}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
 \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
   \begin{longtable}{lp{10cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
   {\end{longtable}}%
 %
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Name & \bfseries Unit\\\hline
   \endhead}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
    & \glsentryunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
 }%
}
```

So, there are two solutions which would just fulfill my needs perfectly: 1) there is a way to have the special character sorted below Z, 2) there is any way to seperate the roman from the `greek letters` (or any idea why the solution from the link above does not work)

I appreciate any hint! Thanks a lot!

Regards