# Error with creating a table of symbols showing units for greek and roman

Tags: tables, symbols, greek, glossaries-extra, roman

Im writing a Dissertation and am having problem compiling my table of symbols. I´m using the example provided from [How to make a custom list of symbols with separated greek and roman symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537607/how-to-make-a-custom-list-of-symbols-with-separated-greek-and-roman-symbols) and have got the minimal example code to run. However, when I adapt it in my thesis I´m getting an error about defining the function `\renewcommand{\glslongextraSubNameFmt}`

I have the following code in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}    \sisetup{detect-all}

\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, nogroupskip, nomain, indexonlyfirst, acronym, symbols, style=long4col, stylemods={longbooktabs}]{glossaries-extra}
%\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{page~}{pages~}

\glsaddkey
{unit}          % new key
{\relax}        % default value if "unit" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
{\glsentryunit} % analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentryunit} % analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsunit}      % analogous to \glstext
{\Glsunit}      % analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSunit}      % analogous to \GLStext

\makeglossaries

% Define the parent roman and greek symbols
\newglossaryentry{romanletter}{
    name={\textbf{Roman letters}},
    description={\nopostdesc}, 
    sort={1}, 
    type=symbols,
}
\newglossaryentry{greekletter}{
    name={\textbf{Greek letters}},
    description={\nopostdesc}, 
    sort={2}, 
    type=symbols,
}

% Don't expand the unit field 
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}
```

The glossary style is defined as follows:

```
% Inform glossary about your own key (see manual v1.41, p.60 about its original definition)

\renewcommand{\glslongextraSubNameFmt}[2]{
    \glssubentryitem{#2}\glstarget{#2}{\glsentryunit{#2}\strut}
}
% Set the new glossary style
\newglossarystyle{long-sym-desc-unit-loc}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long-sym-desc-name}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
        \glspatchLToutput
        \glslongextraSymLocSetDescWidth
        \edef\@glslongextra@begintab{%
            \noexpand\begin{longtable}{%
                    \expandonce\glslongextraSymbolAlign
                    \expandonce\glslongextraDescAlign
                    \expandonce\glslongextraNameAlign
                    %\expandonce\glslongextraLocationAlign
            }}%
            \@glslongextra@begintab
        }   %
        {   \end{longtable}
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \bfseries Symbol%
        & \bfseries \descriptionname %
        & \bfseries Unit %
        \tabularnewline%
        \midrule%
        \endhead%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\glslongextraGroupHeading{4}{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \tabularnewline
        \glslongextraNameFmt{##1} & & %
        \tabularnewline
    }% 
    \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glslongextraSubSymbolFmt{##1}{##2} &
        \glslongextraSubDescFmt{##1}{##2} &
        \glslongextraSubNameFmt{##1}{##2} %
        \tabularnewline
    }%
}
```

I received the following error:

```
Command \glslongextraSubNameFmt undefined. \renewcommand{\glslongextraSubNameFmt}
Package glossaries-extra Error: Glossary style `long-sym-desc-name' undefined. ...ype=symbols, style=long-sym-desc-unit-loc]
\include should only be used after \begin{document}
```

I`ve been trying everything for the last 3 hrs and with no sucess. Please help.

Thanks in advance
Vivan

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would be helpful to know what document class you're using, but if it's an unusual one, can you replicate the problem using, say `article` or `report`?  That will make it much easier for a helper to analyze.

Comment: For the minimal example I`ve used `report`, which complied properly. For the thesis I`m using  the document class `book`

Comment: I've run the example script with book and it works without error.

Comment: That means the problem arises from one of the packages you're using.  Try adding them one by one to your test file until it fails.  Then -- if you can't figure out how to fix it -- post the test file, editing it into your question, along with the parts of the log that identify the versions of the packages used, and I'm sure someone will jump in and tackle it.

Comment: I've managed to somehow resolve the undefined command error `\glslongextraSubNameFmt undefined. \renewcommand{\glslongextraSubNameFmt}` and now only get the error ` ! Package glossaries-extra Error: Glossary style `long-sym-desc-unit' undefined`. I've read https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/#longextra and it shows Glossary style `long-sym-desc-unit` is part of glossary-extra package. Any ideas?