# Refinement of glossaries' symbols list with third column

Tags: tables, hyperref, glossaries

Based on [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units), I have constructed the MWE seen below. It uses the glossaries package to produce a list of symbols with physical units. The list is supposed to have lines between the cells, just like a table. The lines are supposed to be black at the table head as well as at the borders of the list. Between each entry, the lines are supposed to be grey.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} % The option "table" enables coloured tables.

\usepackage[unicode=true,breaklinks=false,backref=false,pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref} % This package is inevitable in the project.

\usepackage[acronym,sort=standard,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.6\linewidth}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of physical quantities} % This is necessary in any case if a list of symbols is to be produced, no matter which style is used.
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{| l | p{\glsdescwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}}
  {\end{longtable}}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \hline
    \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1} \tabularnewline \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\hline\arrayrulecolor{black}}}

\makeglossaries % This seems to be necessary.

\newglossaryentry{sy-c}{name=\ensuremath{c},
    description={velocity of light in vacuum},
    unit={\ensuremath{\rm{m}/\rm{s}}},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=c}

\newglossaryentry{sy-height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
    description={Height},
    unit={\ensuremath{\rm{m}}},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=height}
        
\newglossaryentry{sy-h}{name=\ensuremath{h_{\rm{Pl}}},
    description={Planck's constant},
    unit={\ensuremath{\rm{J}\cdot\rm{s}}},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=hplanck}

\newglossaryentry{sy-pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
    description={Geometrical value},
    unit={},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=pi}
        
\newglossaryentry{sy-power}{name=\ensuremath{P},
    description={Power},
    unit={\ensuremath{\rm{W}}},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=power}
        
\newglossaryentry{sy-x1}{name=\ensuremath{x_1},
    description={Dimensionless energy of particle 1},
    unit={},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=x1}

\newglossaryentry{sy-x2}{name=\ensuremath{x_2},
    description={Dimensionless energy of particle 2},
    unit={},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=x2}


\begin{document}

\gls{sy-c}\\
\gls{sy-height}\\
\gls{sy-h}\\
\gls{sy-power}\\
\gls{sy-pi}\\
\gls{sy-x1}\\
\gls{sy-x2}\\

\printglossary
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % Produce the list of symbols

\end{document}
```

Here is the relevant part of the output pdf:

[image]

Now, there are three problems that appear in the output pdf:

1. Below the last list entry, there is a grey line. This line should be black, however. How can I achieve this?
2. Why are the entries in the unit column hyperlinks? How can I suppress this?
3. How can I suppress that an empty line is created each time a new alphabetic letter is listed?

Comment: Regarding request 3: `nogroupskip` (e.g. as an option or `\printglossary`) should help.

Comment: Regarding request 2: `\glsentryunit{##1}` instead of `\glsunit{##1}` should remove the hyperlink from the unit.

Comment: @TVL: I was under the impression, OP wanted all horizontal lines to be light gray, except for the first two and the last one.

Comment: For 1: change `\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}` to `\arrayrulecolor{black}`.
All horizontal lines were grey and then are black (or red, if you like to ;) )
Edit: I just recognized, that you just want the inner horizontal lines to be grey, the outer black. I'm out, sorry :(

Comment: Thank you, @leandriis, for addressing the problems. Request 2 and 3 are perfectly solved. Request 1 remains.