# glossaries: keeps old entities, not recompiling correctly

Tags: glossaries

I have 2 glossaries. One for acronyms and one for symbols. These lists should only include the used entities. (no `\glsaddall` is used in my project)

When I recompile my file on **overleaf**, only one glossary is refreshing accordingly. The other one is doing weird stuff. It somehow keeps showing old entities and sometimes it is not displaying ones used in the text. It seems that the only way to "refresh" them is "recompile from scratch", what would indicate that temporary files aren't refreshed correctly.

I would appreciate your thoughts and solutions about this problem.

In the following example my problem can be recreated. For recreation of the problem the first compilation must have `\glsaddall` in it and for the second recompile it must be removed first.

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR SYMBOLS LIST =========================================
    \newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
        description={Geometrical value},
        unit={},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
        description={Height of tower},
        unit={\si{m}},
        type=symbolslist}

    \newglossaryentry{energyconsump}{name=\ensuremath{P},
        description={Energy consumption},
        unit={\si{kW}},
        type=symbolslist}




% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR ACRONYMS LIST ========================================
    \newacronym{VRBD}{VRBD}{Violet-Red-Bile-Glucose-Agar}


% ==== EXEMPLARY ENTRY FOR MAIN GLOSSARY ========================================
    \newglossaryentry{Biofouling}{name=Biofouling,description={Some description}}


\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall % when removed and recompile - symbolslist still there

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % list of acronyms
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols
    \printglossary[type=main]                     % main glossary

\end{document}
```

This code is from user31729 posted on  Sep 25, 2015 at [glossaries: How to customize list of symbols with additional column for units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units)

Comment: you are using `\glsunit{##1}` in the list of symbols and so actually "use" every entry mentioned there.

Comment: But also when I delete the whole ```glossarystyle{symbunitlong}``` and simply use for the symbolslist ```\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long]``` it's still not changing the list.

Comment: works fine for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is it also working for you on Overleaf.com? I always must state that it should compile from scratch. Than it's working but it's not when I just recompile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Overleaf where my glossary didn't update properly.

Turned out that there were several unresolved compile errors. You can look up the errors with the "paper-sheet" symbol "Logs and output files" next to the "Recompile" button.

Only after resolving those, in my case by exchanging the Unicode symbol μ by $\mu$ in my text, and then deleting the cached files at the bottom of the logs list (which you already are doing by hitting "recompile from scratch") I was able to just use recompile normally again.

But not sure if that's the solution in your case since one of your glossaries seems to be working.