# How to make custom Index of Symbols and Abbreviatons?

Tags: table-of-contents, symbols, glossaries, overleaf, acronyms

I want to make a custom ***Index of Symbols and Abbreviations*** list provided to me from my thesis template. ***Abbreviations*** ***should not be shown*** in ***the table of contents***, only ***Index of Symbols and Abbreviations*** ***should be shown*** on ***the table of contents***.

***Here is my template:***

[image]

***Here is my MWE:***

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[skip=12pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc, nopostdot, nonumberlist, style=long, automake, acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, maxnames=2, style=bwl-FU]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{latex}
{name=latex,description={Is a mark up language specially suited for scientific documents}}

\newglossaryentry{maths}{name=mathematics,description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}}

\newglossaryentry{formula}{name=formula,description={A mathematical expression}}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={Index of Symbols and Abbreviations}]
\printglossary[title=Abbreviations]
\newpage

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to make it like this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- removed option `toc` from `glossaries`, so toc entries for glossaries are not automatically added
- added toc entry manually:

  ```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index of Symbols and Abbreviations}
  ```
- removed some unused packages

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nopostdot, nonumberlist, style=long, automake, acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, maxnames=2, style=bwl-FU]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{name=latex,description={Is a mark up language specially suited for scientific documents}}

\newglossaryentry{maths}{name=mathematics,description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}}

\newglossaryentry{formula}{name=formula,description={A mathematical expression}}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index of Symbols and Abbreviations}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={Index of Symbols and Abbreviations}]
\printglossary[title=Abbreviations]
\newpage

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works very well. Do you have any idea how I can make my template?

Comment: Just look around for different styles for glossaries. For example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269565/123129) is a question about adding a column with untis to the list of symbols. And [glossaries style gallery](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/). If necessary, you could ask a new question to then solve *one* specific problem.