# How to create a nomenclature- or glossary-like section in LaTeX without downloading the packages?

Tags: formatting

I'd like to create something ideally like this:
[image]

([glossaries package - How to format the positions of the columns and width of the glossary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174652/glossaries-package-how-to-format-the-positions-of-the-columns-and-width-of-the/174665#174665))

but without using the glossary package because I'm having a ton of trouble installing it. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I would like to argue that it will be much more efficient to solve your download/installation issues than trying to reinvent existing packages.

Comment: Most likely issue with glossaries is it is installed but depends on perl (is that your problem) then to use it you need a 3 call chain  either from command line or a defined typeset in your editor (is that your problem)

Comment: under the hood it's just a table, so just use a tabular (and friends) environment to typeset it. of course you won't have the other benefits like `\gls{}` etc., but if you just need the table and don't mind some manual work, it should do you just fine.